# Is there a simple reason for why Mock and SpyBean can't be used together?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, javabeans

Initially, I had annotated a repository with @SpyBean, to track the number of times its methods were called. Then I realized I needed to annotate it with @Mock in order to mock what was returned from the repository.

So I ended up with:

```
...
@SpyBean
@Mock
SomeService someservice;
...
```

which caused all my tests using that service to fail with

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

So I removed @SpyBean and then everything worked again, except the reason I wanted to use @SpyBean was so that I could mock some methods and not others. Does that not work with @Mock?

Edit: someone asked for the file

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {RestApplication.class }, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles({ "test" })
public class SomeServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    SomeService someService;

    //@SpyBean
    @Mock
    SomeRepository someRepository;

    String FILENAME = "txt";

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        someService = new SomeService(someRepository);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFileName() {        

        when(someRepository.findSomethingByAttribute(anyString()))
                .thenReturn(new SomePOJO("", FILENAME, ""));

        someService.runFileName(FILENAME);

        verify(someRepository, times(1)).save(any(SomePOJO.class));
    }
```

Comment: Spying is actually partial mocking so you don't need `@Mock` to mock methods in spy. `@SpyBean` will be enough.

Comment: can you show the test class code ?

Comment: @Deadpool edited

Comment: can you explain a little more...